# JxBrowser update browser

Tags: java, swing, browser, jframe, jxbrowser

I'm using Java JxBrowser to display a website on my swing application. When clicking on a link on this website it will normally open a new tab (in google chrome for example). But my application is opening a popup to display the new window. Is it possible to update the jframe of my application, so that the popup stays in the jframe? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own [`PopupHandler`](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/javadoc/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/PopupHandler.html) to choose where your new [`Browser`](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/javadoc/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/Browser.html) is going to appear :

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser browser = new com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser();
com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView browserView = new com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView(browser);

browser.setPopupHandler(new com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.PopupHandler() {
    @Override
    public com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.PopupContainer handlePopup(com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.PopupParams params) {
        return new com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.PopupContainer() {
            @Override
            public void insertBrowser(com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser popupBrowser, Rectangle initialBounds) {
                // do something with popupBrowser
                com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView popupBrowserView = new com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView(
                        popupBrowser);
                frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                frame.getContentPane().add(popupBrowserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.getContentPane().validate();
                frame.getContentPane().repaint();
            }
        };
    }
});

frame.getContentPane().add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I'm not at home right now, so I will try it later. But is ist possible to just add the popup to the jframe in the insertBrowser() function?

Comment: @Tailor I have edited my answer to show you how to replace the content of the JFrame with the content of the popup.